# When does a SQL Alchemy query actually make a query to the database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am looking at some code that conditionally creates a query object and then looks at the results of the query. For example:

```
query = self.session.query(Person).filter(Person.last_name == "Jones") #line 1
#some other logic
query = query.filter(Person.title == "VP Sales") #line 3
#some other logic
query.first() #line 5
```

When would the query actually hit the database? Ideally, the query would only run when I need to use the results of the query (ie. line 5).

I tried to look in the SQL Alchemy docs (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html) but was not able to find this information.

Comment: Try to locate "lazy" in documentation as that has been the term you're looking for.

Comment: It *couldn't* run it at line 1, because it doesn't know if you're going to add more filters later. Same for line 3; it's only when you actually request the data that you're asserting that the query is done being mutated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it would hit the database when calling `.first()`, the rest of the lines are simply formatting a query object.

That being said, the query would also get fired as soon as you would iterate over your `query` object or if you would call `.all()` on it.

```
query = self.session.query(Person).filter(Person.last_name == "Jones") 
query = query.filter(Person.title == "VP Sales") #line 3

for person in query:    # hit db here
    print(peron)

# OR

persons = query.all()   # hit db here

# OR

persons = list(query)   # hit db here (note that this has the same effect as calling .all())
```